# How do I fill the background of my device context after scrolling?

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm making a little tool to help build a game. In this tool, I need to draw a sort of simple flowchart.

To do this; I've created a `wxFrame` app. Inside the frame is a single `wxAuiNotebook`. Right now there's a single custom object that inherits from `wxScrolledWindow` in this notebook.

The idea is that the custom object would just draw my simple flowchart. It inherits from `wxScrolledWindow` because I imagine that the flowchart will be larger than the available space.

I've set this all up in wxSmith within Code::Blocks.

Everything looks good, until I scroll. Suddenly, there's a grey bar. I believe the grey bar is the underlying background color coming through. I believe it's coming through because I'm doing a `DrawRect` call to fill the background with a white rectangle. I believe I'm not determining the origin and extents of my `DrawRect` call correctly.

[image]

You can see in my picture, that once scrolled down I've got that grey background coming through.

Here is the code of my custom control:

```
struct StoryNodeData
{
    wxString title;
    wxString text;
};

class StoryNode
{
public:

    void Paint(wxGraphicsContext* gc) const
    {
        gc->SetBrush(*wxTRANSPARENT_BRUSH);
        gc->SetPen(*wxBLACK_PEN);
        gc->DrawRoundedRectangle(m_point.x,m_point.y,m_size.x,m_size.y,10);
        gc->Clip(m_point.x,m_point.y,m_size.x,m_size.y);

        gc->DrawText(m_nodeData.title,m_point.x + 5, m_point.y + 5);

        gc->DrawText(m_nodeData.text,m_point.x + 5, m_point.y + 20);

        gc->ResetClip();
    }

    StoryNodeData m_nodeData;
    wxPoint m_point;
    wxSize m_size;
};

class FlowchartPanel : public wxScrolledWindow
{
public:
    FlowchartPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, wxPoint position, wxSize size, long style)
    :
        wxScrolledWindow(parent, id, position, size, style)
    {


        Connect(wxEVT_PAINT, wxPaintEventHandler(FlowchartPanel::OnPaint));
        Connect(wxEVT_SIZE, wxSizeEventHandler(FlowchartPanel::OnSize));
        Connect(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_TOP, wxScrollWinEventHandler(FlowchartPanel::OnScroll));
        Connect(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_BOTTOM, wxScrollWinEventHandler(FlowchartPanel::OnScroll));
        Connect(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_LINEUP, wxScrollWinEventHandler(FlowchartPanel::OnScroll));
        Connect(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_LINEDOWN , wxScrollWinEventHandler(FlowchartPanel::OnScroll));
        Connect(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_PAGEUP , wxScrollWinEventHandler(FlowchartPanel::OnScroll));
        Connect(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_PAGEDOWN , wxScrollWinEventHandler(FlowchartPanel::OnScroll));
        Connect(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_THUMBTRACK , wxScrollWinEventHandler(FlowchartPanel::OnScroll));
        Connect(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_THUMBRELEASE , wxScrollWinEventHandler(FlowchartPanel::OnScroll));
    }

    void OnScroll(wxScrollWinEvent& event)
    {
        wxScrolledWindow::HandleOnScroll(event);
        Refresh();
        Update();
    }

    void OnSize(wxSizeEvent& event)
    {
        Refresh();
    }

    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event)
    {
        wxPaintDC dc(this);
        PrepareDC(dc);
        auto gc = wxGraphicsContext::Create(dc);
        if(!gc)
            return;

        gc->SetFont(*wxNORMAL_FONT,*wxBLACK);

        gc->SetBrush(*wxWHITE_BRUSH);
        auto min = DoSizeCalc();
        auto sz = GetSize();
        auto st = dc.GetDeviceOrigin();
        if(min.x < sz.x)
            min.x = sz.x;
        if(min.y < sz.y)
            min.y = sz.y;
        gc->DrawRectangle(st.x,st.y,min.x,min.y);

        for(const auto& n : m_nodes)
            n.Paint(gc);

        delete gc;
    }

    void AddNode(const StoryNode node)
    {
        m_nodes.push_back(node);

        auto sz = DoSizeCalc();

        SetScrollbars(10,10,sz.x/10,sz.y/10,0,0);
    }

    wxSize DoSizeCalc()
    {
        wxSize min(0,0);
        for(const auto& n : m_nodes)
        {
            auto extentX = n.m_point.x + n.m_size.x;
            auto extentY = n.m_point.y + n.m_size.y;
            if(extentX > min.x)
                min.x = extentX;
            if(extentY > min.y)
                min.y = extentY;
        }

        return min;
    }

protected:

    std::vector<StoryNode> m_nodes;
};
```

I've tried a few different methods to determine the correct origin and size of my white rectangle but none work. I've added the custom event handlers for the scroll events thinking that maybe I just needed to force a redraw.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To adjust the origin when drawing on `wxScrolledWindow`, just call its `PrepareDC()` method.

Also, even though it has nothing to do with your problem, there is no reason to use `Connect()` in 2018, use simpler and more powerful `Bind()` to connect your event handlers instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `bind`. I am already calling `PrepareDC`. The issue may be how I am determining the rectangles extents.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed `GetDeviceOrigin()` call but not `PrepareDC()` above. If you do call `PrepareDC()`, you should use logical, i.e. independent of scrolling position coordinates. Conversely, if you want to use physical coordinates (e.g. paint entire window), do it _before_ calling `PrepareDC()`. I don't really understand what are you trying to do with `st`...